# Android blocking notifications but in ios it works Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, push-notification, android-notifications

in my Flutter application Im using the awesome notifications in version 0.6.13

I already had make the configuration to use it, and on IOS it works perfectly but on android, always that i want to requestUserPermission to send a android notification I get this screen [photo of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIcyk.png)

basically the sistem are telling me that i requested to block the users notification for this app but i never did it. does any one know what could it be?

here are my code implementation [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIcyk.png)